# How do you reset a Linux host to its first-boot state?

Tags: boot, installation, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, almalinux

We are building a generic deployment image and I want to clean/delete all the host-specific details.  (This a RHEL8/Oracle 8/Alma 8 system.)

This is what I have so far:

```sh
# rm -rf /etc/.etckeeper/* # if you use etckeeper
# rm -rf /etc/hostname /etc/mailname /etc/krb5.keytab
# rm -f /var/lib/dhcpd/*
# rm -rf /var/lib/sss/db/*
# rm -rf /var/tmp/*
# rm -rf /tmp/*
# rm -f /root/.*_history
# rm -f /home/*/.*_history
# rm -f /.bash_history
# rm -f /etc/lvm/archive/*
# rm -f /etc/lvm/backup/*
# rm -f /root/.viminfo
# rm -f /root/.less*
# rm -f /root/.rnd

# echo 'root:<newpass>' | chpasswd

# find /var/log/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 truncate -s0
# find /var/log/ -type f -name '*[0-9]' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
# postsuper -d ALL
# yum --enablerepo=* clean all

# systemctl stop sshd 
# systemctl stop NetworkManager
# rm -f /etc/machine-id
# rm -f /etc/ssh/*key*
# rm -f /var/lib/NetworkManager/*

# sync
# prevent writing .bash_history and poweroff:
# poweroff & kill -9 $PPID $$
```

Is there anything else needed here after a minimal EL install?  This is an absolute *minimal* install, almost nothing is installed except some minor tweaks and cloud packages.

Comment: Try booting to terminal mode..    https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90554/how-to-boot-linux-to-command-line-mode-instead-of-gui    and see if you can remove startup and other apps that way.

Comment: A few others come to mind easily. /etc/hostname, /etc/mailname, /etc/krb5.keytab, /etc/.etckeeper/*, /var/lib/NetworkManager/, /var/lib/sss/db/. After you kill /var/log/*, will lastlog and wtmp be re-created automatically? Do you have anything new in /etc/pki? For a generic deployment image I would strongly suggest using a kickstart file to pin down your exact configuration. My builds using kickstart take less than 15 minutes per server.

Comment: You really cannot "cleanup" the root filesystem of a running system. You would be better off booting from a LiveCD/DVD/USB (which would use its own intramfs for a rootfs), and then mount this filesystem. Note that the various mountpoints for tmpfs and sysfs will be empty directories that don't need cleaning.

Comment: @doneal24, I like the kickstart idea, but I don't think AMI's support that :( .  This is a minimal install, almost nothing is there with some minor tweaks.  (ie, we don't have `dhcpd` on the image but I put it on the list from an older script we used to use.)

Comment: @KJ7LNW If the system allows you to boot off of an ISO image (cd or usb) and the network interfaces are visible from the bios/uefi then you can use  kickstart. My particular image is ISO-based. It loads the kernel from the local media with the network configuration contained in the grub command line. I generally use a static IP but the setup allows for DHCP, bonded interfaces, and vlan tagging.